# What kind of number is that?

Tags: java, number-formatting, nanotime, hdrhistogram

after doing a benchmark with HdrHistogram i got this number as value:

142.22182267674.623

That should be Nanoseconds but what kind of number is that?

```
       Value        Percentile      TotalCount 1/(1-Percentile)

1382023.167         0.000000000000          4           
1.0019646119.935    0.100000000000     100206          
1.1138084280.319    0.200000000000     200069          
1.2556002347.007    0.300000000000     300035          
1.4374289512.447    0.400000000000     400079          
1.6793147103.231    0.500000000000     500482         
2.00102273908.735   0.550000000000     550994          
2.22111333605.375   0.600000000000     600111          
2.50120393302.015   0.650000000000     650281          
2.86129385889.791   0.700000000000     700720          
3.33138378477.567   0.750000000000     750271         
4.00142807662.591   0.775000000000     775667          
4.44147102629.887   0.800000000000     800121         
5.00151800250.367   0.825000000000     825758          
5.71156497870.847   0.850000000000     850548          
6.67160927055.871   0.875000000000     875580           
8.00163074539.519   0.887500000000     888411          
8.89165490458.623   0.900000000000     900830         
10.00167772159.999  0.912500000000     913078        
11.43169919643.647  0.925000000000     925254       
13.33172201345.023  0.937500000000     938262      
16.00173275086.847  0.943750000000     944125       
17.78174348828.671  0.950000000000     950208         
20.00175422570.495  0.956250000000     956346          
22.86176496312.319  0.962500000000     963139         
26.67177704271.871  0.968750000000     969798         
32.00178241142.783  0.971875000000     972386         
35.56178778013.695  0.975000000000     975149
```

that are some results of the benchmark. that are not two numbers in one and yes i have learned math but not with numbers structured like these....

Comment: Probably two numbers that were printed together without a space.

Comment: this definitely is not a java number (int, long, float, etc...)

Comment: Well, now you can clearly see that you have **four headers** but only **three strings** in each line. There are two numbers stuck in each line for sure.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes. after formatting the results I have copied the 1/(1-percentile) number in front of the value.

Comment: the results of mean and max should have bee the first advise

Comment: #[Mean    = 92681504.670, StdDeviation   = 52566008.206]

#[Max     = 183207198.719, Total count    =      1000000

Comment: are you using http://hdrhistogram.github.io/HdrHistogram/JavaDoc/org/HdrHistogram/DoubleHistogram.html ? because to me seems like it using all the allocated nano digits and then converts it to seconds (i don't know if makes sens of it is like that)  so you will have seconds.nanotime (nanotime is as well xxx.xxx format) so you will have this format for seconds.nanotime: yyy.xxx.xxx - which is strange.